# Somebody have AccExplorer32.exe?

Tags: windows, winapi, sdk

I tried getting AccExplorer32 from this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631969.aspx and many others, but it says that Page cannot be found. Can someone *please* upload it somewhere, I'll appreciate it.

EDIT:

AccExplorer32 is not included in the current SDK (7.1). It's replaced with UISpy, which is also not included in 7.1. But you can download it from here: http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2009/09/15/uispy-ndash-download-it-here.aspx (broken link)

Comment: It's obsolete, I think UISpy.exe is its replacement.  Included with the full SDK, not the one that comes with Visual Studio.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx

Comment: Now MS wants us to use these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373661.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a forum with a valid link that might solve your problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/81dbfae1-7f57-44e2-ac47-9fd20b1bef54

Answer (score 2):

As you say, UISpy.exe is not in the v7.1 SDK. It has been replaced by **Inspect.exe** which is in the v7.1 SDK Tools, works very well, and does both MSAA and UIA.

More details on Inspect is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yup; the new version of inspect includes a treeview pane in addition to the object properties pane, so it effectively functions as a replacement for both UISpy (which was UIA only) and AccExplorer32 (MSAA only).

Answer (score 0):

[AccExplorer32.exe](https://github.com/lihas/WindowsAccessibilitySamples/blob/master/Tools/AccExplorer32.exe)

I had great difficulty in finding this tool (among others from MS used for accessibility testing), so I have uploaded a copy to my GitHub repo.

1. [Accessibility tools](https://github.com/lihas/WindowsAccessibilitySamples/tree/master/Tools)
2. [AccExplorer32.exe](https://github.com/lihas/WindowsAccessibilitySamples/blob/master/Tools/AccExplorer32.exe)
3. [inspect32.exe](https://github.com/lihas/WindowsAccessibilitySamples/blob/master/Tools/inspect32.exe)

I am working on a legacy project where the newer tools like Accessibility insights are not that helpful. The older tools were focused more towards [MSAA (Microsoft Active accessibility)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Active_Accessibility), while newer tools are focused more towards [Microsoft UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation).

Comment: All your github.com/lihas links are dead